# JAVA RUN TIME ENVIRONMENT (JRE) for ARM(I.Mx6)

Tags: java

I have an JAVA executable (JAR) File which i developed in Ubuntu 16.04.

Now i want to Run that JAR FILE in MY TARGET ARM Processor(i.mx6), for that i need the JRE to be installed.

From ORACLE Site i found that 4 different JDK's available. which one i have to choose and whats the difference between each one ?

IN JAVA SE has,

1.Linux ARM 32 Hard Float ABI   77.89 MB    jdk-8u144-linux-arm32-vfp-hflt.tar.gz
2.Linux ARM 64 Hard Float ABI   74.83 MB    jdk-8u144-linux-arm64-vfp-hflt.tar.gz

IN JAVA SE Embedded has,

1.ARMv5/ARMv6/ARMv7 Linux - SoftFP ABI, Little Endian 2 102.62 MB   ejdk-8u144-linux-arm-sflt.tar.gz

2.ARM v6/v7 Linux - VFP, HardFP ABI, Little Endian 1    114.95 MB   ejdk-8u144-linux-armv6-vfp-

Also i want to Know Why the ORACLE has provided two different ARM JDK's 
1. JAVA SE Standard edition
2. JAVA SE Embedded Edition

Comment: Not all ARM processors are equal ; most of the older and smaller ones have no support for "hard" floating point numbers, and they may arrange bytes in computer memory in a different way (little endian, big endian, etc). you should look at what kind of processor you intend to run your code on, and select the proper SDK accordingly.

Comment: i.MX6 (like the raspberry Pi) adheres to the following : `ARMv6/ARMv7 Linux - VFP, HardFP ABI, Little Endian1 version.`

Comment: so basically, that answers your question i think

Comment: Also i want to Know Why the ORACLE has provided two different ARM JDK's 1. JAVA SE Standard edition 2. JAVA SE Embedded Edition ?

Comment: I already answered that question more or less ; the armvX processors are fundamentally different from the other, and thus have a completely different instruction set. the JIT & runtime must be able to work with the processor's instruction set, so there are separate versions for "embedded" processors. (i am trying to keep this simple and abstract, you could write books about what exactly is different and why)